# How to hide the network address image upload function in Tinymce

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvI8u.png)
How to hide the network address image upload function in Tinymce

I would like to remove the address upload function and only retain the local upload function

I am using Vue+JavaScript

my code:
**config**: {
label: tl('编辑器', 'Editor'),
showLabel: true,
changeTag: true,
labelWidth: null,
tag: 'tinymce',
tagIcon: 'rich-text',
defaultValue: null,
span: 24,
layout: 'colFormItem',
required: true,
regList: [],
document: 'http://tinymce.ax-z.cn'
},

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.